# Use beans as a pipeline and also conditionally skip flows

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to apache camel. I want to invoke a bean method. Inside the bean method i want to set a header which i want to use in a subsequent step to conditionally skip the flow or next destination.i also want to know how to pass output of method response as route output or as input to next destination which would be another bean. Can someone share me snippet for the same.

Answer (score 0):

See the pipes and filters EIP (which is the default mode of routing in Camel)

- http://camel.apache.org/pipes-and-filters.html

So just setup a route to route to your beans, and the output is input on the next, and so forth.

For the header, then read about bean parameter binding, or use Exchange as the parameter type.

A good source on using beans with Camel is the free chapter 4 of the Camel in Action book: https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition

There is also details on the Camel website: http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I think your response should help me a lot. I will try and let you know how it goes.